# Not getting expected result in google API explorer

Tags: google-apis-explorer

Iam using google chat api explorer to get chat message its working fine but in one case its not giving expected result.
**Case** : When iam copying some text and image from browser with mouse like left click and select text and image than copy it and paste in chat. The image which has copied is not a image but its URL which is displayed but when iam trying to get messages from google chat api explorer iam only getting the text but not the image/url. I have used google playgroud it is also giving same result. I have also used google Take out its giving the image url but i cant use google takeout.

But i have tried is in the header value of request i have used **Accept** header value **application/json;odata.metadata=full** but it is also not working.
Will appreciate if someone helps me